# Cannot set file owner to NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller

Tags: .net, windows, security, acl

Using explorer I can set the owner of a file I have created to "NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller" and it does get set. I have verified with DIR /Q.

But when I use the following C# code on Windows 7 SP1 X64 :

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo("TrustedFile.txt");
FileSecurity security = info.GetAccessControl();
NTAccount Sid = new NTAccount("NT SERVICE\\TrustedInstaller");
security.SetOwner ( Sid );
info.SetAccessControl( security );
```

I get the following exception, event when running with Administrator privileges.

```
**System.InvalidOperationException: The security identifier is not allowed to be the owner of this object.**
   at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Object excepti
onContext)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String name, AccessControlSections includeSections, Object exceptionContext)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String name, AccessControlSections includeSections)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity.Persist(String fullPath)
   at System.IO.File.SetAccessControl(String path, FileSecurity fileSecurity)
   at System.IO.FileInfo.SetAccessControl(FileSecurity fileSecurity)
   at SetFileOwner.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Only system files are owned by that user, and my guess is you're not the system...

Answer (score 0):

You have to impersonate a windows user that will have the rights to do so inside asp.net.

Impersonation is usually done for for Database login inside asp.net.